# How to get metrics on Firebase storage use?

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

So I just discovered Firebase doesn't offer any kind of metrics about the use of storage files which is quite disappointing to say the least.

Since Firebase uses Google Cloud Storage I wondered I could use `gsutil` like any other GCS bucket. [Here are the docs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/logging).

Unfortunately, logging isn't enabled by default, and apparently can't be set for Firebase buckets. When doing `gsutil logging set on ...` this error comes up:

> CommandException: "logging set on" command spanning providers not allowed.

Isn't there a way to get some metrics about storage usage in Firebase other than implementing our own system?

Comment: Can you give the full command (faking out the name of your bucket, but not the uri structure).  It looks to me like this error is due to a bad argument.  possibly a poorly formed gs:// uri.

Answer (score 1):

Wow, I didn't even know we published these logs--nice find! Why we like having built so closely on top of GCS. You can definitely use that every 24 hours to aggregate your own usage stats, but it would be great if we could provide that for you.

On the error provided, [taking a look at the source](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gsutil/blob/cfe99899910375bf3695b7e4a119ee0074110259/gslib/util.py#L1351) indicates that the `...` in your command is likely the source of the error. Can you post the rest of the command so we can see how you're setting up buckets (feel free to scrub bucket name, but we need to see the schemes)? It looks like you 1) will need billing enabled, and 2) need to have all buckets by the same provider (all GCS, or all S3, etc.).

We're still investigating breaking out usages stats (bandwidth, storage, and number/type of each operation), but that it will likely take a while since we have to aggregate them from GCS.